# Memory leaks in 0 rows of code.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, memory-leaks

Look at this simplest application:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <crtdbg.h>  

void main(void)
{
   _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

It produces the next output in debug pane:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{94} normal block at 0x012EA298, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <Dw      > 44 77 D9 00 00 00 00 00 
{93} normal block at 0x012F0DA8, 20 bytes long.
 Data: <  /   /   /     > A8 0D 2F 01 A8 0D 2F 01 A8 0D 2F 01 01 01 CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```

**`Detected memory leaks!`** how is it possible?
Win10, VS2015, target platform version 10.0.14393.0

Comment: Most likely some statically-scoped objects that are internal to the runtime C library, and are constructed when the C library initializes. Not really a memory leak.

Comment: Probably false positives from object created by the run time not being destroyed by the time it checks for leaks.

Comment: Why do you care? You're about to exit your application. There's no such thing as a memory leak once your process exists, unless the OS itself is buggy. When the process terminates, all the memory it had allocated is freed automatically. Nothing you do in your code will change that.

Comment: I care because of this confuses me when I catching **my** leaks. I want to suppress **not-mine** leaks.

Comment: Please read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" this with next manipulations:

1. Let `stdlib` check and show memory leaks by itself before exit

   ```
   _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
   ```
2. To see the message I put break point in `exit.cpp:129` on

   ```
   ExitProcess(return_code);
   ```

The result code:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <crtdbg.h>  

void main(void)
{
   // Show memory leaks before exit
   _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
   auto a = new int[33333];
   //_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();  // DO NOT USE
}
```

Now I can see only **MY** memory leaks in debug pane!

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{95} normal block at 0x014B4F48, 133332 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```

*33333 * 4 = 133332.*

Thanks to @JamesBean and [MSDN article "Finding Memory Leaks Using the CRT Library"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)